# How do I know if VDD on STM32 is stable? NPOR input

Tags: stm32

I'm using a STM32F038x6 which have a pin called NPOR. NPOR is a pin which can turn on a switch who enables the RTC, backupregisters etc.

[image]

But NPOR need to be low(0) before VDD is fully stable. When VDD is stable, then NPOR need to be high(1).

[image]

**Question**

How can I make so NPOR will be high when VDD is stable?
Sounds difficult to me, because who knows when VDD is stable?

Can't I just connect NPOR to VDD because I have capacitors on VDD which makes the VDD input stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> who knows when VDD is stable?

That's what [power supply supervisor ICs](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/pmic-supervisors/691) do. The ones having O/D output can be used.

Comment: Why does ST have NPOR? Did they forgot that they could avoid it, like the rest of the STM32 processors?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I don't know. But it appears that they put NPOR as a replacement for a GPIO. Maybe to allow the designer to use his/her own POR mechanism instead of the MCU's built-in (yet configurable) POR mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a voltage divider between VDD and NPOR. According to the data sheet, the NPOR input high voltage is 0.5VDD + 0.2. So you could choose the voltage divider values such that only when VDD reaches its max value does the voltage divider output reach the input high threshold of NPOR.

This is under the assumption that when VDD reaches its max value, it is considered "stable enough".